# Prove $\lvert|x+ y|^{p-1}(x+y)-|x|^{p-1}x-|y|^{p-1}y\rvert\le C(|x|^\epsilon |y|^{p-\epsilon}+|x|^{p-\epsilon}|y|^\epsilon)$ for all $x, y$

Tags: inequality, reference-request

Given $p>1$, I would like to show that there exists constants $C>0$ and $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that
$$
\left\lvert \left\lvert x+ y\right\rvert^{p-1}(x+y) - \left\lvert x \right\rvert^{p-1}x - \left\lvert y \right\rvert^{p-1}y \right\rvert \le C\left(\left\lvert x\right\rvert^\epsilon \left\lvert y\right\rvert^{p-\epsilon} + \left\lvert x\right\rvert^{p-\epsilon}\left\lvert y\right\rvert^\epsilon\right)
$$
for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $0<\epsilon < \epsilon_0$.

While I hope this inequality is true, I am unable to prove it and therefore not 100% sure. Any suggestions on how to approach it would be appreciated.

What I have tried:

- Some calculus methods. For instance, I tried defining $f(x,y,\epsilon)$ to be the difference between the right-hand and left hand side (where I will figure out later how large $C$ needs to be). Then, I was hoping to take the derivative with respect to $\epsilon$ and somehow show that $f(x,y,\epsilon)$ approximates $f(x,y, 0)$ in an appropriate way.
- I also tried going by contradiction and constructing a sequence $(x_m), (y_m), (\epsilon_m)$ such that $0 < \epsilon_m < 1/m$ and
  $$
  \left\lvert \left\lvert x_m + y_m\right\rvert^{p-1}(x_m+y_m) - \left\lvert x_m \right\rvert^{p-1}(x_m) - \left\lvert y_m \right\rvert^{p-1}y_m \right\rvert > m\left(\left\lvert x_m\right\rvert^{\epsilon_m} \left\lvert y_m\right\rvert^{p-\epsilon_m} + \left\lvert x_m\right\rvert^{p-\epsilon_m}\left\lvert y_m\right\rvert^{\epsilon_m}\right)
  $$
  for each $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Unfortunately, this led me nowhere.

Comment: The constant $C$ depends on $p$?

Comment: @Kroki It can! I have a suspicion we might be able to make it independent of $p$ in compact intervals within $(1, \infty)$, but this is not necessary for my proof.

Comment: I wonder if maybe the following post's answer could be adapted to the present case: [Generalize the binomial equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3875004) It's similar but it doesn't deal with different possible powers on the RHS...

Comment: @BrunoB Thank you for the link, I don't see how to generalize this proof from $p-1$ to $p-\epsilon$. The argument heavily realize on use of the derivative of the map $t\mapsto t^p$ which is how we get the bound with a $p-1$ exponent. I tried to see if my result is a consequence with Young's product inequality but the exponents unfortunately did not work out.

Comment: This is not gonna be (easily) generalisable either, but for the specific case $p = 2$ your claim is true by choosing $t := \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\varepsilon/2}$ in the family of inequalities $ab = (at)(bt^{-1}) \overset{\mathrm{Young}}{\leq} \frac{1}{2}\left(a^2t^2 + b^2t^{-2}\right)$ for $a = |x|$ and $b = |y|$. That's because $2ab = 2|xy| = (x+y)^2 - x^2 - y^2 = ||x+y|^2 - |x|^2 - |y|^2|$. Wanted to share just in case, but that's unlikely to help by itself.

Comment: Some thoughts that I had after reading Bruno's link: if we want to show that $|x+y|^p - |x|^p - |y|^p \leq C(|x|^\epsilon |y|^{p-\epsilon} + |x|^{p-\epsilon} |y|^\epsilon)$, we can rearrange this to $|x+y|^p \leq |x|^p + |y|^p + C(|x|^\epsilon |y|^{p-\epsilon} + |x|^{p-\epsilon} |y|^\epsilon)$. Then if we rescale to make $x$ have unit norm, then the RHS is independent of $x$, so we simply want to maximize the LHS, and this happens when $x$ and $y$ are collinear. This reduces the problem to a one-dimensional inequality.

Comment: @BrunoB Thank you both for the input, I'll have more time to look at this in a few days and see what I can do! I'll post an answer if I figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $z=-x-y$. Then $x+y+z=0$ and
$$\left\| \left\| x+ y\right\|^{p-1}(x+y) - \left\| x \right\|^{p-1}x - \left\| y \right\|^{p-1}y \right\|=$$
$$\left\| \left\| x \right\|^{p-1}(-x) + \left\| y \right\|^{p-1}(-y)+\left\| z \right\|^{p-1}(-z) \right\|=$$
Let $(u,v,w)$ be a permutation of $(x,y,z)$ such that $\|u\|\le \|w\|$ and $\|v\|\le \|w\|$.
Then the triangle inequality implies that
$$\left\| \left\| x \right\|^{p-1}(-x) + \left\| y \right\|^{p-1}(-y)+\left\| z \right\|^{p-1}(-z) \right\|=$$
$$\left\| \left\| u+v \right\|^{p-1}(u+v) - \left\| u \right\|^{p-1}u-\left\| v \right\|^{p-1}v \right\|=$$
$$\left\| (\left\| u+ v\right\|^{p-1} - \left\| u \right\|^{p-1})u +(\left\| u+ v\right\|^{p-1}- \left\| v \right\|^{p-1})v \right\|\le $$

$$\left(\left\| u+ v\right\|^{p-1} - \left\| u \right\|^{p-1}\right)\|u\| +\left(\left\| u+ v\right\|^{p-1}- \left\| v \right\|^{p-1}\right)\|v\|\le $$

$$\left(\left(\left\|u\right\|+ \left|v\right\|\right)^{p-1} - \left\| u \right\|^{p-1}\right)\|u\|+\left(\left(\left\|u\right\|+ \left|v\right\|\right)^{p-1} - \left\| v \right\|^{p-1}\right)\|v\|=$$
$$\left(\left\|u\right\|+ \left|v\right\|\right)^p-\|u\|^p-\|v\|^p.$$

Since $(u,v,w)$ be a permutation of $(x,y,z)$ such that $\|u\|\le \|w\|$ and $\|v\|\le \|w\|$,
we have that
$$C(\|u\|^{p-\epsilon}\|v\|^\epsilon+\|u\|^\epsilon \|v\|^{p-\epsilon})\le
C(\|x\|^{p-\epsilon}\|y\|^\epsilon+\|x\|^\epsilon \|y\|^{p-\epsilon}).$$
Thus to provide the required inequality it suffices to provide
$$\left(\left\|u\right\|+ \left|v\right\|\right)^p-\|u\|^p-\|v\|^p\le C(\|u\|^{p-\epsilon}\|v\|^\epsilon+\|u\|^\epsilon \|v\|^{p-\epsilon})$$

Put $a=\|u\|$ and $b=\|v\|$. Thus it suffices to provide
$(a+b)^p-a^p-b^p\le C(a^{p-\epsilon}b^\epsilon+a^\epsilon b^{p-\epsilon})$.

Put $\epsilon_0=1$. Swapping $a$ and $b$, if needed, we can suppose that $a\le b$.
If $a=0$ then the left hand side is zero, so the inequality holds.
Suppose that $a>0$ and put $t=b/a\ge 1$.
Thus we have to provide $(1+t)^p-1-t^p\le C(t^{p-\epsilon}+t^\epsilon).$

Note that if $\epsilon\le p-1$ then since $(t^{p-\epsilon}+t^\epsilon)-(t^{p-1}+t)=(t^{p-1}-t^\epsilon)(t^{1-\epsilon}-1) \ge 0$
it suffices to provide $(1+t)^p-1-t^p\le C(t^{p-1}+t)$.

By Lagrange's theorem, there exists $s\in (t,t+1)$ such that $(1+t)^p-t^p=ps^{p-1}<p(t+1)^{p-1}$. Then
$$(1+t)^p-1-t^p<p(t+1)^{p-1}\le p(2t)^{p-1}\le 2^{p-1}pt^{p-\epsilon},$$ so we can put $C=2^{p-1}p$.

Let $2\le p\le 3$.
Note that in this case $\epsilon_0\le p-1$.
By Taylor's formula with the remainder in Lagrange's form, there exists $s\in (t,t+1)$ such that
$$(t+1)^p=t^p+pt^{p-1}+\tfrac{p(p-1)}2t^{p-2}+\tfrac{p(p-1)(p-2)}6s^{p-3} \le t^p+pt^{p-1}+pt+1,$$
so we can put $C=p$.

I shall try to decrease the value of $C$ for the remaining values of $p$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how your get the second inequality? I.e. how do you go from the third line to the fourth line? Put otherwise, how do we know that $(||x|| + ||y||)^{p-1} - ||x||^{p-1} \ge |\, ||x+y||^{p-1} - ||x||^{p-1}|$? It would suffice to show that $(||x|| + ||y||)^{p-1} + ||x+y||^{p-1} \ge 2||x||^{p-1}$.

Comment: @Quoka Oops, there was an error. I am sorry for this and thanks for noticing. I fixed this gap in the updated answer .

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!